# how do I send a transaction for signature to metamax?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

```
let byteCode = await web3.eth.getCode(contractAdress, (data) => {
    return data
})

const txHash = await ethereum.request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [
        {
            from: user_address,
            to: main_adress,
            gas: "2000000"
            data: byteCode,
            nonce: "sending own token "
        }
    ],
})

console.log(txHash)
```

I want to send my token to another wallet using a honey mask. After executing the code , an error appears
.
If my solution is incorrect, you can suggest or give a working version of the driver
version web3.js 1.6.1

Error Details

```
Message: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: sending own token

Code: BigNumber Error
```

Answer (score 0):

nonce is a number in hex or decimal format (or string that could be parsed as INT).

read more about nonce here:
https://coinmarketcap.com/alexandria/glossary/nonce

You can try to leave this field empty, and ask library to place latest nonce automatically.

P.S. `let byteCode = await web3.eth.getCode(contractAdress, (data) => { return data })` not the data you are looking for. I can recommend for you to use special libraries like `web3.js` or `ethers` to deal with sending transaction. They have good documentation about sending tx's. Example in `ethers`: https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/121#issuecomment-367453923

Answer (score 0):

Nonce has a specific meaning, it is not a field to leave comments like `"sending own token "`.

Nonce is the transaction index of the `from` address. e.g. if this is the 1st transaction sent by `user_address`, nonce must be 0. If it is the 9th transaction, nonce must be 8. It must therefore be a number, but you are giving it a string. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

By the way, you don't need to manually specify the nonce field at all. If you don't specify a nonce it will be automatically filled with what is probably the correct value.

Comment: I manage to send a transaction, but at the same time some other coin is taken from me.
here is the error 
(Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { code: -32603, message: "[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"exceeds block gas limit\"}}}'", stack: "Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"exceeds block gas limit\"}}}'" })

Comment: I have a contract, and there is an account on which there is a token. I want to send a transaction to metamask with the amount of token and gas.
Maybe I 'm going the wrong way ?